# not been updated for Face ID Message

Tags: ios, swift, face-id

previously my app is using touchID for login and now i am going to implement faceID for login the app, and my app getting this message when the app start local authentication.

How can I prevent this message from show up when I use faceID for login?

The message content: "**This app was designed to support Touch ID. It has not been updated for Face ID.**"

Note: I had NSFaceIDUsageDescription with values on my info.plist

[image]

Appreciated if any suggestion is given!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Adding a new key named: "Privacy - Face ID Usage Description" and insert a string value solved my issue!

Comment: This is the proper answer. Just to add some clarification for anyone who may not know where to add it, this is a key in the `Info.plist` file for your app. When you click the "+" to add a new row to the plist file in Xcode, select this item from the list, then add a string as the value.

Comment: I'm confused... In the question you note that you already had this value set in the Info.plist.